# "Unknown transaction override 0" Error at Hardhat contract deployment

Tags: erc-20, hardhat

Hi I got this "unknown transaction override 0"

when I was trying to deploy an Openzeppelin ERC20 contract at a local Hardhat EVM node:

```
Error: unknown transaction override 0
    at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (.../node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:1194:27)
    at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:1244:53)
    at step (.../node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (.../node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (.../node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you reveal your deployment code? This will help a lot.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I got it solved. please see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mistakenly added extra contract constructor argument!

```
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('ERC20_contract_name');
  token = await Token.deploy(tokenName, tokenSymbol, [user1Addr]);
```

The correct Hardhat script should be:

```
  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('ERC20_contract_name');
  const token = await Token.deploy('tokenName', 'tokenSymbol');
```